# Should I Return in a Python Function if Return Value Won't Be Used?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following code:

```
import sys


def error(msg):
    print(msg)
    sys.exit()
```

I could also do this:

```
import sys


def error(msg):
    print(msg)
    return sys.exit()
```

The program is exiting when I call this function, so does it matter if I return the sys.exit() call as it'll never be used as a value?

Here is a slightly different example:

```
def clear_screen():
    print('\033c')
```

Should I use this or should I return the print function call even if that value is not being used?

Comment: Every Python function returns a value, like it or not. If you do not return a value explicitly, then the function returns `None`. Your question is unclear.

Comment: How are you using this function?

Comment: If you are not calling your error function in assigning a variable it doesn't really matter of you return a value or not.

Comment: No, don't do the pointless `return`.  It won't hurt anything, but it's unnecessary and it invites confusion as the reader tries to figure out what you're returning.  If you need to return early from a function that returns `None`, just use a `return` statement on its own rather than returning some other `None` value.

Comment: The general convention is that functions that are used only for side effects don't return anything, and you shouldn't have needless `return` statements.